# NameError (uninitialized constant Confbridge::ConfbridgeMaxParticipant):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i try to delete data on rails but i get an error

which says:

> A NameError occurred in confbridges#destroy:
>
> NameError (uninitialized constant Confbridge::ConfbridgeMaxParticipant):
>     app/controllers/confbridges_controller.rb:55:in `destroy'

this is line 55 of my code:

```
  def destroy
    @confbridge.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to confbridges_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

What is the possible problem in here ? thanks :)

Comment: How do you get `@confbridge`? Please show that code.

Comment: Also please post your models code.

Comment: Thanks @Pavan. I check my model and remove this code `has_many :confbridge_max_participants, :dependent => :destroy` and it works . . but what does that mean?

Comment: That is not the solution to your problem. Do you have `confbridge_max_participants.rb` model? If so please post that code.